# Правильное написание bat-скрипта

Tags: bat, скрипт

подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше написать скрипт. Требования к скрипту.

1. Создать папку типа год-месяц-день-час(каталог arhive)в каталоге(каталог base)
2. Переместить содержимое каталога base в каталог arhive. изначально в каталоге base содержаться 5 папок в каждой их которых лежит файл
3. Создать папку типа год-месяц-день-час на сетевом хранилище (каталог nas)
4. Скопировать содержимое каталога arhive в каталог nas

есть такие наработки, при выполнении этого скрипта создается каталог arhive в каталоге base,
содержимое каталога base (5 папок содержащих по файлу) копируется в каталог arhive, далее создается каталог nas на сетевом хранилище, а копирование к сожалению не работает (нужно именно копирование, а не перемещение), может подскажете альтернативные скрипты для данной задачи, заранее спасибо

```
set mm=%DATE:~3,2%

set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%

set curdati=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%

    md E:\BackUpBuh\%curdati%

    E:

    cd E:\BackUpBuh

    move buhbds %curdati%

    move buhbmn %curdati%

    move buhgva %curdati%

    move buhlrb %curdati%

    move buhmal %curdati%

    move buhmta %curdati%

    move buhmva %curdati%

    move buhpas %curdati%

    move buhpmv %curdati%

set h=%TIME:~0,2%

set d=%TIME:~3,2%

set s=%TIME:~6,2%

set dd=%DATE:~0,2%

set mm=%DATE:~3,2%

set yyyy=%DATE:~6,4%

set curdate=%dd%-%mm%-%yyyy%

set curtime=%h%-%d%-%s%

set curdatetime=%curdate%_%curtime%

    md \\NAS\Data_Back_Up_\BackUpBuh\%curdatetime%>nul 2>nul

    robocopy E:\BackUpBuh \\NAS\Data_Back_Up_\BackUpBuh
```

Comment: для копирования в windows cуществует команда `copy` [документация](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy)